How do I dump framebuffer from Wayland client?
Is it possible to dump a screenshot of the Wayland client after drawing?
I am studying the Weston example, https://github.com/krh/weston/blob/master/clients/simple-egl.c
I wonder if it is possible to access the memory of the wl_shm, then copy it via mmap?
